# Workbook saving issue within a loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I've been trying to find solution to this but I'm pretty much a beginner in VBA and not all of the stuff I checked made sense to me or simply didn't work.
I'm running a macro with a loop that is supposed to go through multiple files within one folder. It is pretty simple and works fine with everything I put inside there. However, I would also like it to save the file with a specific name (based on the cell B2). Problem is, no matter how I structure the saving command the loop restarts and once again tries to save the same file - over and over. I tried having the new file saved in a different directory (since the loop goes through the folder I thought this might resolve the issue, only it didn't). Is there any way to have the loop that opens the files, make the necessary changes to the formatting and then saves them with a specific name to finally close them?

Here is my code:

```
Sub test21()

'
' test21 Macro
'

'
    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xFdItem As Variant
    Dim xFileName As String
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*.xls*")
        Do While xFileName <> ""
            With Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)
                    Columns("R:R").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("A1:I1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 1695487
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("J1:Q1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 2849846
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("A1:Q1").Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
xFileName = Range("B2")
            End With
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xFdItem & xFileName & ".xlsx"
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Loop
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: first, - you should load all filenames to the list, and later loop through that list.
Otherwise your `Do While xFileName <> ""` will always find the file in the folder and will not stop

Comment: What is the **name or index of the worksheet** you are trying to modify in the workbooks you're opening? Is it `Sheet1` or a worksheet with some other name? Is it the first (left-most) or last (right-most)? Or will you just be gambling with whichever is selected?